# How can I change the color of a font with function text( ) in Matlab?

Tags: function, matlab, text, colors

```
marker={'r','b','g'};
for i=1:size(X,3)
    for r=1:size(X,1)
        for c=1:size(X,2)
            text(X(r,c,i),Y(r,c,i),Z(r,c,i),num2str(dof(c,r,i)))
        end
    end
end
```

For each value of `i`, I want to use a different color as given in `marker` to plot `num2str(dof(c,r,i))`. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the wrong computer (no matlab for testing) right now, but

> text(X(r,c,i),Y(r,c,i),Z(r,c,i),num2str(dof(c,r,i)), 'Color', marker{i})

should work. There will be problems if size(X,1)>3 this way however.